# Unable to search using getelementbyid value and click search using IE and VBA

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer, dynamics-crm

I have been trying to get a search result in Microsoft CRM website for a custom view, and below is the code I have written:

```
Sub Web_macro()
Dim IE As Object
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://ascensus.crm.dynamics.com/main.aspx?appid=6b918724-06a4-428b-923c-af272020c699&pagetype=entitylist&etn=asc_psgopportunityproduct&viewid=5b711f57-1500-e611-811e-005056b61789&viewType=1039"
Do While IE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 4, Now)
Loop
Set doc = IE.document
doc.getElementById("quickFind_text_0").Value = "var"
doc.getElementById("quickFind_button_0").Click
End Sub
```

but it not changing the value of the search field and click search, just returns the original view. Below is the script of the web

```
<div class="gn ib ic cf id fv ie if flexbox">
< div class="ig ih a ax bs ii cl flexbox" data-id="data-set-quickFind-container"><input title="Select to enter data" class="x u bs ij ik il " id="quickFind_text_0" aria-label="Search this view" type="text" placeholder="Search this view" value="" data-id="quickFind_text_0" autoComplete="off">
<button tabindex="0" title="Start search" class="x im u b ik in io ip flexbox" id="quickFind_button_0" aria-label="Start search" type="button" data-id="quickFind_button_0"><span class="symbolFont SearchButton-symbol hs iq ic bs " id="quickFind_button_icon_0"></span></button>
</div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue using the code you give. I tested and it can change the input value and click the button. Is there any error when you run the script? Are the elements you want to operate in an iframe? If possible, please provide the screenshot of the html structure of the web page.

Comment: @YuZhou, no I did not receive any error message, just the search was useless, and had the original search results appeared on the screen. I am new to HTML, so I do not understand what is an iframe. For your reference, I have attached the screenshot here - [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10R1EX_VNH_2WXtoBP5zCRH0Yn3cU1vsj/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: From your screenshot, I can't tell if there's `<iframe>` in the page. You could refer to [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp) about what is iframe. Please check if iframe exists in the page. Besides, you could try to add a wait before send the value and click the button. Maybe the script is running faster than the page load.